# Outlook 2010 "forgets" password

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, domain

I am running Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 Pro x64 on a domain. Outlook is connecting to exchange, and the username and password should be pulled from my logon credentials.

The problem is, about every few hours, outlook "forgets" what my password is. In the taskbar, a caution triangle appears, and in the bottom right hand corner of exchange, a "Needs Password" replaces "Connected to Microsoft Exchange." Simply clicking "Needs Password" fixes the issue, and new messages are downloaded.

What could the issue be? What could be timing out?

Edit:
Also, at times the following window appears:

[image]

This is my Security Settings

[image]

Comment: Wonderful!  Microsoft has increased security by forgetting passwords!  Innovation!  On a totally almost related note:  Does the time duration/frequency of Outlook's forgetfulness coincide in any way with possible DHCP settings?  Specifically, the lease duration and expiration time?

Comment: dont believe so. Im on about 2.5 day leases, and I forget password a lot more often than that.

Comment: This last time it remembered for about 5 minutes.

Comment: Hmmm, Outlook Alzheimers?  Doesn't look good!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recreating your outlook profile? That's usually my first step with Outlook glitches: it's often down to corruption in the profile.